# Equivalent of Git's "amend last commit" in perforce

Tags: git, perforce

New to Perforce. After submitting my change list, I realized that I had missed one tiny thing that's not worth writing a submit message about. Thus I submitted this change with the exact same message, thinking that it would be around the same thing as amending my last commit in Git. Evidently it wasn't, as a new revision with this absurdly tiny change was created instead.

Is there any way to merge the two commits (on the exact same file) now that I've already submitted them both? How would I handle this situation next time?

Comment: Even with git, you shouldn't amend a commit that you've already pushed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have "admin" or higher permissions you can "take back" submitted changelists with the "p4 unsubmit" command:

```
% p4 help unsubmit

unsubmit -- unsubmit a changelist, making it a shelf

p4 unsubmit [-n -r remote] file[revRange]...

    The unsubmit command takes one or more submitted changelists and
    undoes the submission, leaving the changelist as a shelved change
    with the same content. The changelist can then be unshelved and
    further updated prior to resubmitting it.

    ...

    The unsubmit command requires admin permission granted by
    p4 protect.
```

Once the changelists go from "submitted" to "pending" you can combine them, discard them, modify them, etc prior to submitting them again.

If you're not an admin, all history is immutable once submitted.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you are the Perforce admin your can't edit the files submitted, but you can edit the commit message.

The Perforce admin could you p4 obliterate possibly to get rid of the intermediate file version, but I'm not sure what that would do to your commits. It certainly wouldn't combine them.